# How to access server data in Angular 2 component to fill dynamic form fields

Tags: node.js, http, get, angular2-forms, formgroups

I am trying to load user profile data and addresses(multiple addresses) in my form.
So I need to put addresses in the loop.So that I can create dynamic form fields with data.

**personalInfoComponent.ts:**

```
var data = this.personalInfoService
        .getPersonalInfoData(this.driver_id)
        .subscribe(arg => {this.driverData = arg.profile,
                           this.address_data = arg.addresses});
```

**personalInfoService.ts**

```
getPersonalInfoData(driver_id) 
 { 
    return this.http.get('/getPersonalInfoData/'+id).map((res: Response) => { 
        return res.json(); }); 

 }
```

Here I'm trying to use that data
**personalInfoComponent.ts:**

```
 const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.personal_info_form.controls['addresses'];   
  this.address_data.forEach(item => {

      let newGroup = this._fb.group({
        address: [item.address, Validators.required],
        city: ['', Validators.required],
        state: ['', Validators.required],
        zip: ['', Validators.required],
        years: ['', Validators.required],
      });
      arrayControl.push(newGroup);
  });
```

In the above code, I can be able to get data from backend, but I cannot access the **address_data** in my **personalInfoComponent.ts**

Comment: What type of error do you get when trying to access your variable?

Comment: I can see an empty array but not error on my console.
One more important thing is
I can able to get address data in my view file(component.html)